# Delete all 0 byte files in HDFS which is created between a date range

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

How do i delete files in HDFS  for a date range . ie to delete 0 byte files created between yesterday and 150 days from today.This is to be done in a shell script.

I am using below command to delete all 0 byte files but i need one where i can provide date range

```
 hdfs dfs -ls -R $directory/* |grep -Ev "txt|xml|csv|mrc"| awk '$1 !~ /^d/ && $5 == "0" { print $8 }' | xargs -n100 hdfs dfs -rm
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
# Create reference file with the date of today 00:00:00.000000 am 
# as our upper date limit (excluded bound)
# that's equal to all yesterday up to 11:59:59.999999 pm
touch -d 'today' /tmp/before.tmp # before today is yesterday

# Create reference file with the date of 150 days ago as our lower date limit
# that's equal to 150 days ago 00:00:00.000000 am
touch -d '150 days ago' /tmp/after.tmp

# Find and delete files
find \
  "$directory" \
  -maxdepth 1 \
  -type f \
  -size 0 \
  -anewer /tmp/after.tmp \
  -not -anewer /tmp/before.tmp \
  -regex '.*/.*\.\(txt\|xml\|csv\|mrc\)' \
  -delete
```

Breakdown of the `find` command:

- `"$directory"`: find starting in this path from variable `$directory`
- `-maxdepth 1`: limit search to this directory without descending sub-dirs
- `-type f`: search actual files (no directory, no links...)
- `-size 0`: search files with an actual size of 0
- `-anewer /tmp/after.tmp`: search files that were accessed more recently than this reference file's date `/tmp/after.tmp`
- `-not -anewer /tmp/before.tmp`: and that where accessed at most or before the reference file's date `/tmp/before.tmp`
- `-regex '.*/.*\.\(txt\|xml\|csv\|mrc\)'`: search files whose full-name with path match the POSIX RegularExpression '.*/.*.(txt\|xml\|csv\|mrc)'
- `-delete`: delete the files that are found matching all the previous options predicates